# How to run fsck on Ubuntu manually?

Tags: ubuntu, fsck

I switched off my laptop while it was restarting. And when I tried to open it again it asked me to do `fsck` manually. I don't have any proper understanding of how to do `fsck`. So I typed `yes` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the command line. And it keeps typing `y` and not stopping. It is an Ubuntu 18.04.

What should I do? Also can you please tell me the steps on how to run `fsck` manually?

Comment: You've invoked the program `yes` which will be printing `y` until the world ends. Press Ctrl+C to stop.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps on how to run fsck manually?

Comment: Pressing CTRL+C won't end the World?!

Comment: @JoepvanSteen No, it will copy it into clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

You [should not run *fsck* on a mounted file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47953/can-i-run-fsck-or-e2fsck-when-linux-file-system-is-mounted). Instead, the way to repair the file system is to boot from another device, such as a Live Ubuntu USB.

- [Download files and create a Live Ubuntu USB](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) (or use a device you used to install Ubuntu).
- Shut the PC.
- Insert the USB stick.
- Hold the key to change the PC's boot order (e.g., <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> on some PC models), power on and select the USB drive to boot.
- Select *try* Ubuntu, not install, again.
- You can then run *fsck* from Terminal, or just as easily, open the [*Disks*](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/) GUI and perform repairs to each partition there.

BTW, I've found that *frequently* repairs *fail on the first attempt*, without any explanation of the issue, and then succeed on a second attempt. Not confidence inspiring, but so far, it has worked well... and is far faster than the alternative, restoring from the last disk image.

Comment: I'd expect the terminal `fsck` to work on disks mounted in ReadOnly mode (disks and partitions NOT having "0" [zero] in the RO column of `lsblk` output) - i.e. run from recovery mode.